# Set Search Domains from Terminal

Tags: macos, dns

Is there a file that I can view/edit from terminal that has a list of the search domains?

I know it's possible to set these up from the DNS tab in the Network preferences, but is there a way to do it over the terminal?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You wouldn't necessarily need to view/edit a specific file. In OSX, Mac allows you to modify or set DNS configs among other things by running the [networksetup](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/networksetup.8.html) command. The full path is: /usr/sbin/networksetup

Since it's in /usr/sbin  -you should be able run the networksetup command from anywhere within the terminal.

You can run something like this:

```
networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet labs.example.com staging.example.com
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Custom TLDs were (sometimes) failing for me on Mac. So, I used a search domain to 'default' to a *.dev url (for local development).

If you need to reset/clear out your custom search domains that you set via the above command use this:
`networksetup -setsearchdomains Ethernet Empty`

Also, to programmatically get your active network interface, look at this bash script: http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/223446/111516